# Another Android Request Permission dialog not showing issue

Tags: android, permissions, request, dialog

I've spend a day on this issue, and I'm stumped. I've read through numerous similar questions, and tried all the suggestions, but nothing worked for me.
I have an app, with a preference screen where the user can turn on Bluetooth. The preference screen sends an intent to the MainActivity, which then checks security permissions and if needed requests permission.

I am building against version SDK version 32.
In Manifest I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="true"/>
```

In MainActivity I check if permission is already granted:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Objects.equals(intent.getAction(), CustomIntent.CHECK_BLUETOOTH_SECURITY_PERMISSION)) {
            int check = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( thisActivity, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT );
            if ( check == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED )
                getPermission( Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT, RequestCodes.BT_SECURITY_REQUEST.ordinal() );
        }
```

and if not, I request permission.
When requesting permission, I have tried the old way with:

```
public void getPermission( String permission, int requestCode ) {
    if ( shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale( permission ) ) {
        // TODO: display a dialog to explain the reason for needing the permission
        Toast.makeText( this, "Need to put together an explanation for the permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
    } else {
        requestPermissions( new String[]{ permission }, requestCode );
    }
}
```

I have tried both with CompactActivity.requestPermissions and with just requestPermissions as above.

and I have also tried with the new way. In onCreate I have:

```
activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
    new ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions(), new ActivityResultCallback<Map<String, Boolean>>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(Map<String, Boolean> result) {
            Log.e("ActivityResultLauncher", ""+result.toString() );
            Boolean areAllGranted = true;
            for ( Boolean b : result.values() ) {
                areAllGranted = areAllGranted && b;
            }
            if ( areAllGranted )
                Log.e( "ActivityResultLauncher","It worked");
            else
                Log.e( "ActivityResultLauncher", "wah wah wah");
        }
    });
```

and in getPermission() i then call

```
activityResultLauncher.launch(new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
        });
```

But no matter what I do, the user dialog asking the user to grant permission never show, and the onPermissionRequestResult just immediately return with False, i.e. Denied.

I don't see any error messages in the LogCat (outside of the log entries I put there myself). I've also tried to step through the Android libraries to see i can see any exception thrown, but all looks fine there as well.

**UPDATE**
Just as I posted this, I tried to clear the emulator device.
After that, the first time I ran the code, the app crashed, hard.
I was able to catch this in logCat

> Attempting to launch an unregistered ActivityResultLauncher with >contract
> androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts$RequestMultiplePermissions
> and input [Ljava.lang.String. You must ensure the
> ActivityResultLauncher is registered before calling launch().

I do register the activityResultLauncher in onCreate. So I'm not clear on why it doesn't know it's registered.
It's also weird that this error only happens first time I run the app after clearing device files.

Then I launched the app again, (without changing anything in my code) and this time it worked. The dialog was displayed, and I could grant permissions.

Anyone know what in the world is going on?

Comment: Have you tried this against an actual device? The emulator doesn't support Bluetooth afaik

Comment: Did you find a solution or reason? I'm seeing something similar on OnePlus 7T Pro.

Comment: Just found that this is most probably my reason: 
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/permissions#dialog-visibility

"Starting in Android 11, if the user taps Deny for a specific permission more than once during your app's lifetime of installation on a device, the user doesn't see the system permissions dialog if your app requests that permission again."